# Taxonomy vocabularies terms with at most 1 parent term?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Taxonomy Manager module to manage my Taxonomy vocabularies.

How can I restrict the parents of the items to 1 ? I don't want my customer being able to add more than 1 parent to a taxonomy term.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With core taxonomy that is not possible.

I would suggest you build a simple module that uses either the [hook_taxonomy](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_taxonomy/6) to catch the *insert* and re-act on that. 
It has, however, no *validate* method, so you are actually a little "too late" when disallowing on *insert* or *update*.

The other way, would be slightly harder and uses [hook_form_alter](http://drupal.org/node/751826) to add your own _validate callback to the forms where your users insert the extra terms. You can run any validation code in that callback, to detect the depth and post a [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/form_set_error/6) if the depth is too deep.